# I want to make an autocliker app for both android and ios, but it can also take screenshots and recognize a specific image in the screen

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, ui-automation, game-automation

I am a cs student but i dont have eny experience with mobile apps. I want to make an autocliker app for a specific game that can also take a screenoshot and recognize the location of a specific image in the screen, but i dont have any idea where to start.

I would like to make it for both android and ios,
i have heard you can make an ios app with android studio, can i use it for this specific kind of app?

Also my brother(also a cs student) wanted to make an app exactly like that and the only way he found was something called AnkuLua, but its only for android and its complicated for the user. You have to download separately AnkuLua, the script for the autocliker and the pictures and then run the game. I want something more user friendly where you just download the autoclicker,run the game and then activate it.

EDIT:
Okay so i found out about the AccesibilityService api that i will use if i do it with android studio, so my only concern is about the ios app. is there any way i can make the ios app with android studio, using "almost" the same code? and if not what is the equivalent of AccesibilityService api for xcode

Answer (score -2):

Try unity! You can make any kind of app with it and for all platforms, it's not olny for games.